# UIImageview in UITableView: unexpected resizing on scroll or tap

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview, custom-cell

I'm facing a problem with one of my tableView, when I decode JSON and put my imageview with a size constraint it works, but when I scroll the tableview or tap on the image, the imageview returns to its original size.

I use a custom cell to avoid this type of problem but it doesn't work :

First load :

[image: First load :]

On tap or Scroll :

[image: On tap or Scroll]

My custom Cell :

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {


@IBOutlet var picture: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var title: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var price: UILabel!


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

My tableView func :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell:CustomCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! CustomCell

    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame:CGRectZero)
    tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(rgb: 0x007AFF)
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(rgb: 0x007AFF)

    cell.title.text =  repos[indexPath.row].title
    cell.price.text = repos[indexPath.row].price

    let urlString = repos[indexPath.row].picture_url! as String,
    imgURL = NSURL(string: urlString as String)

        // If this image is already cached, don't re-download
        if let img = imageCache[repos[indexPath.row].picture_url!] {
            cell.picture.image = img
            cell.picture.frame = CGRectMake(5,0,61,43)
            println("image présente")
        }

        else {

            loading.startAnimating()
            // The image isn't cached, download the img data
            // We should perform this in a background thread
            let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: imgURL!)
            let mainQueue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()
            NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: mainQueue, completionHandler: { (response, data, error) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    // Convert the downloaded data in to a UIImage object
                    let image = UIImage(data: data)
                    // Store the image in to our cache
                    self.imageCache[repos[indexPath.row].picture_url!] = image
                    // Update the cell

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                        if let cellToUpdate = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
                            cellToUpdate.imageView?.image = image
                            cellToUpdate.imageView?.frame = CGRectMake(5,0,61,43)

                            println("image reload")
                        }
                    })
                }
                else {
                    println("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            })
        loading.stopAnimating()
        }
    return cell
}
```

Do you have an idea from where the problem comes ?

Thank you

Comment: got an answer to this?

Comment: Yeah, take a look at my comment below.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to solve the problem is that you set AutoLayout in CustomCell.

All you have to do is setting Width and Height. Like this,

[image]

As a supplement, it is better to adjust UIImageView's contentMode and clipsToBounds as needed.

Comment: ok, i tried, now it's work but only for the first row ! the others are still resizing

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i solved the problem, in fact in my code, if my picture is not already cached, i re download it, when it's done i put in in a new tableviewcell (cellToUpdate), and i dont have UIImageView define for this cell, by the way i used the default "imageView?", which resize my image to the default value.

I just replaced my cellToUpdate by the name of my customCell , with my custom imageView, and it works :

```
cell.picture.image = image
cell.picture.frame = CGRectMake(5,0,61,43)
```